# How to subclass a CuPy array?

Tags: python, cupy

For NumPy one can use

```
class A(np.ndarray): pass
a = np.random.rand(10, 10).view(A)
print(a) # OK
```

But for Cupy, the following operation leads to segfault:

```
class A(cp.ndarray): pass
a = cp.random.rand(10, 10).view(A)
print(a) # segfault
```

I've looked through the document but find little infomation. Is this expected?
I'm using CuPy 5.2, Python 3.6.8 and CUDA10.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [numpy.ndarray.view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view), it takes two input arguments: `dtype` and `type`. If the `dtype` argument is a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`, it is interpreted as `type` argument.

On the other hand, according to the documentation of [cupy.ndarray.view](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.ndarray.html#cupy.ndarray.view), it takes only one input argument: `dtype`. I guess `cupy.ndarray.view` does not support `type` argument now.